# Numeric in-text citation by mistake

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I was using in-text citations which showed as (Author, Year) but suddenly they have started appearing as numeric such as [1], [2]. Looking for suggestions on how to fix it.
I use the following package:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

I use the following command to prin references at the end:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

Comment: `natbib`'s default (if you don't load the package with any options and do not issue any other commands like `\setcitestyle` to change its behaviour) is to produce author-year citations. The code you have shown so far should do that. You have to investigate if you document loads `natbib` several times with different options or changes the settings with `\setcitestyle`. If you can share a short, compilable example document that reproduces what you are seeing with as little code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), we might be able to help.

Comment: @moewe, there are no repetitions of loading natbib and I do not use setcitestyle. When I tried the code below, the references in-texted loaded as per default. There seems to be an error in the rest of the file.

Comment: ``` \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}

foo \cite{calonico2019} \\
baz \citep{ashworth2018}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}

Comment: Delete the temporary `.aux` and `.bbl` files and compile again (with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX - where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). If that does not help, you will have to find the problematic code in your document via binary search (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: @moewe, I cleared cache and also spotted the error in one of the bibliography entries which were forcing the citations to be numeric.  Thanks for your help!